# Next.js API Application :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, edamam-api

I have just been introduced to Next.js and have been tasked to create a dynamic website that uses data retrieved from an API. The web app should contain at least two pages: an index page and a page that displays details about the topic that the user selects on the index page.

I have chosen to make use of the Edamam recipe API and to use the search functionality on the index/ home page to render the recipe results on the page to fulfil the brief. I am, however, experiencing some trouble iterating over the data.

Please see below the error:

[image]

My code is as follows:

**- Pages:**

**index.js**

```
// Imported the Link API to support client-side navigation.
import Link from "next/Link";
// import { Spinner } from "@chakra-ui/react";
// Imported AppDisplay to set the holistic style of this page.
import AppDisplay from "../components/AppDisplay";
// Imported Carousel from React Bootstrap.
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";
// Importing the SearchForm component.
import SearchForm from "../components/SearchForm";

/**
 * Styled the home page.
 */

const carouselStyle = {
  overflowX: "hidden",
  overflowY: "hidden",
  height: "auto",
  width: "auto",
};

const logoStyle = {
  height: "450px",
  width: "auto",
  marginBottom: "70px",
};

/**
 * Applied the styles and passed the AppDisplay props.
 * @returns Styled home page, displaying a styled introduction header text section an image and a header component.
 */

const Home = (props) => {
  const { search, onInputChange } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <AppDisplay>
        <div>
          <Carousel variant="dark" style={carouselStyle}>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Breakfast.jpg"
                alt="First slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Dinner.jpg"
                alt="Second slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Dessert.jpg"
                alt="Third slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Bake.jpg"
                alt="Third slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Burger.jpg"
                alt="Third slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Casserole.jpg"
                alt="Third slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Pizza.jpg"
                alt="Third slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/static/images/Pudding.jpg"
                alt="Third slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <img
                  src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoMain.png"
                  alt="Grumble Logo"
                  style={logoStyle}
                />
                <SearchForm value={search} onChange={onInputChange} />
                <div id="edamam-badge" data-color="white" z-index="1"></div>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
          </Carousel>
          {/* <div id="edamam-badge" data-color="white"></div> */}
        </div>
      </AppDisplay>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exported home page to be generated.
export default Home;
```

**recipes.js**

```
// Imported the Link API to support client-side navigation.
import Link from "next/Link";
// Imported AppDisplay to set the holistic style of this page.
import AppDisplay from "../components/AppDisplay";
// Imported Recipe component.
import RecipeData from "../components/RecipeData";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const Recipes = (props) => {
  const { recipes } = props;
  console.log("props:", props);

  const recipeDetails = recipes.map(({ recipe }) => ({
    label: recipe.recipe.label,
    source: recipe.recipe.source,
    totalTime: recipe.recipe.totalTime,
    cuisineType: recipe.recipe.cuisineType,
    mealType: recipe.recipe.mealType,
    healthLabels: recipe.recipe.healthLabels,
    dietLabels: recipe.recipe.dietLabels,
    image: recipe.recipe.image,
    ingredientLines: recipe.recipe.ingredientLines,
    url: recipe.recipe.url,
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <AppDisplay />
      <Header />
      <div>
        {recipeDetails.map((recipes) => (
          <RecipeData recipes={recipes} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exported home page to be generated.
export default Recipes;
```

**- Components:**

**Header.js**

```
// Imported the Link API to support client-side navigation.
import Link from "next/Link";
// Imported Font Awesome library and icons. Also added "import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";" to allow styling the icons.
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";

/**
 * Styled the header component.
 */

// Setting the header's position to absolute and set the padding and background color to transparent.
const headerStyle = {
  // position: "absolute",
  height: "auto",
  width: "auto",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
  padding: 5,
  backgroundColor: "#393d49",
  zIndex: 1,
};

// Set the size (height x width) of the header's logo.
const logoStyle = {
  height: "80px",
  width: "auto",
};

// Set the margins and the font color, size and decoration of the header links.
const linkStyle = {
  margin: "auto 40px auto 20px",
  color: "#ffffff",
  fontSize: 20,
  textDecoration: "none",
};

// Set the recipe page's visibility to hidden.
const recipeLinkStyle = {
  visibility: "hidden",
};

// Created onMouseOver and onMouseOut event handler functions to change the font colors of the header links once hovered
// over and to change back the colour when the links are no longer hovered over.
const changeFontColor = (e) => {
  e.target.style.color = "#f1b374";
};

const changeBackFontColor = (e) => {
  e.target.style.color = "#ffffff";
};

// Set the font size and the right margin of the home icon.
const iconStyle = {
  fontSize: "1.1rem",
  marginRight: "5px",
  color: "#ffffff",
};

/**
 * Attached the event handlers to the links with onMouseOver and onMouseOut.
 * @returns The styled header component with navigatable, styled links.
 */

const Header = () => (
  <div style={headerStyle}>
    <img
      src="/static/images/GrumbleLogoHead.png"
      alt="Grumble Logo"
      style={logoStyle}
    />
    <Link href="/">
      <a
        style={linkStyle}
        onMouseOver={changeFontColor}
        onMouseOut={changeBackFontColor}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} style={iconStyle} />
        Home
      </a>
    </Link>
    <Link href="/recipes">
      <a style={recipeLinkStyle}>RECIPES</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);

// Exporting the Header to the recipe page.
export default Header;
```

**AppDisplay.js**

```
// Imported the Link API to support client-side navigation.
import Link from "next/Link";
// Importing the Next built-in component to append elements to the head of the page.
import Head from "next/head";

/**
 * Created a global style.
 */

// Set the application's margins, padding and font size and families. Also set for the vertical and horizontal overflow to be hidden.
const appDisplayStyle = {
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  overflowX: "hidden",
  overflowY: "hidden",
  fontSize: 15,
  fontFamily: "Staatliches, Trebuchet, Helvetica",
};

/**
 * Added the links to utilize React Bootstrap and the Google font.
 * @param {*} props Children pages for appDisplayStyle to render - index, recipes.
 * @returns The application's general styling, with appended links, for use in the pages.
 */

const AppDisplay = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches"
      />
      {/* <script src="https://developer.edamam.com/attribution/badge.js"></script> */}
    </Head>
    <div style={appDisplayStyle}>{props.children}</div>
  </div>
);

// Exporting AppDisplay for use on the pages.
export default AppDisplay;
```

**SearchForm.js**

```
// Imported the Link API to support client-side navigation.
import Link from "next/Link";
// Imported React library and hooks.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// Requiring Axios.
import axios from "axios";
// Imported components from React Bootstrap.
import { Form, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";
// Imported Font Awesome library and icons. Also added "import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";" to allow styling the icons.
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";

/**
 * Styled the SearchForm component.
 */

// Set the search container's position to absolute and aligned it to the top and left. Also set the left margin to counter the left position.
const searchContainer = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "68%",
  left: "45.5%",
  marginLeft: "-100px",
};

// Set for the form container to display as flex and the direction to row. Also set the position to relative to allow the icon to appear inside
// the input area.
const formContainer = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
  position: "relative",
};

// Set the size (height x width), the padding and the background color of the input element.
const searchInputStyle = {
  height: "35px",
  width: 300,
  padding: 5,
  backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
};

// Set the icon's position to absolute and aligned it to the top and left. Also set the height, the font size and color and for the cursor to
// to a pointer once it hovers over the icon.
const iconStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  left: "275px",
  top: "8px",
  height: "20px",
  fontSize: "1rem",
  color: "#808080",
  cursor: "pointer",
};

const SearchForm = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  console.log("recipes:", recipes);

  const API_ID = "some_sensitive_data";
  const API_KEY = "some_sensitive_data";

  useEffect(() => {
    sendApiRequest();
    return () => {
      setRecipes({});
    };
  }, []);

  // An asynchronous function fetching data from the API.
  const sendApiRequest = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      //   `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${search}&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=bacon&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=12`
    );
    // const data = await res.json();
    setRecipes(res.data.hits);
    console.log("res.data.hits:", res.data.hits);
  };

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearch();
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={searchContainer}>
        <Form
          className="search-form"
          style={formContainer}
          onSubmit={sendApiRequest}
        >
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="search-bar mr-sm-2"
            style={searchInputStyle}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            value={search}
            //   isDisabled={isLoading}
          />
          <a href="/recipes">
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faSearch}
              style={iconStyle}
              type="submit"
              className="search-button"
              id="search"
              onClick={sendApiRequest}
            />
          </a>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exported the RecipeListings to SearchForm.
export default SearchForm;
```

**RecipeData.js**

```
// Imported React library and hooks.
// import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const RecipeData = (props) => {
  console.log('props:', props)
  const {
    label,
    source,
    totalTime,
    cuisineType,
    mealType,
    healthLabels,
    dietLabels,
    image,
    ingredientLines,
    url,
  } = props;

  return (
    <Card col-3 offset-1>
      <Card.Header>
        <h5>{label}</h5>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Recipe By:</th>
            <td>{source}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Preparation Time:</th>
            <td>{totalTime}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Cuisine:</th>
            <td>{cuisineType}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Meal Type:</th>
            <td>{mealType}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Health:</th>
            <td>{healthLabels}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Dietary Information:</th>
            <td>{dietLabels}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Img src={image} alt="Recipe Photograph" />
      <Card.Body>
        <ul>
          {ingredientLines.map((ingredients) => (
            <li>{ingredients}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Card.Body>
      <Card.Footer>
        <Button href={url} target="_blank">
          Method and More
        </Button>
      </Card.Footer>
    </Card>
  );
};

// Exported recipeDetails to be generated.
export default RecipeData;
```

I have run console.logs on recipes (SearchForm.js - empty array returned), props (RecipeData.js - empty object returned) and on res.data.hits (SearchForm.js - returned data).

I seem to be having trouble defining the props in the pages/ components, but am not having any success sorting it out.

I would appreciate it if anyone is willing to assist.

Answer (score 0):

based on the pictures at the beginning api is returning 500 internal server error, in this function adda error handler `sendApiRequest` if the error occurs you can capture and display a message or anything you want tbh.

```
const sendApiRequest = async () => {
    axios.get(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=bacon&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&from=0&to=12`
    ).then(res => {
 setRecipes(res.data.hits);
}).catch(err => console.log('there was an error in sendApiRequest ', {err})
  };
```

when it comes to the map error, you can either define defaultProps in case the props of your components are undefined or null or you can add `?`

```
<div>
      <AppDisplay />
      <Header />
      <div>
        {recipeDetails?.map((recipes) => (
          <RecipeData recipes={recipes} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

it will not throw an error if you add a null check like this

EDIT:
Based on your comment below, your issue is related to the state management. I highly recomend you to use redux or any other state management if you can

but ill explain how should the state management should be with the useState hook

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'



const MainComponent = () => {
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState([])


return (
<>
// this is where you are sending the request to the api
   <ComponentFetchesTheData fetchData={setSomeState} />
// this is where you display the results
   <ComponentDisplaysTheData data={someState} />
</>

)
}

export default MainComponent
```

Comment: Thank you so much for having a look. I have made the changes as suggested, but am unfortunately still experiencing the same errors. I think that the recipes.js page is not receiving the information from the index page or the api? Is it recommended to reiterate the api's link on the recipe page?

Comment: how do you use `recipes` data out of the SearchForm.jsx? i dont see any component that you are passing that state data

Comment: I have referenced it again in the recipes.js page file. I am attempting to iterate over the data in this file and render the search results to display on this page.

Comment: you need to move your state outside of search form, then pass it as a prop to other files with useState hook, otherwise the data you fetched will stay inside the search form

Comment: Would it be recommended to place it directly in the page files?

Comment: if you mean parent components then yes, store the data in the parent component and pass it to the child components as props, i suggest you to have a look reacts docs about state management

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235346/discussion-between-naim-mustafa-and-chanelle-bosiger).